# To get the date difference between a datetime and nullable datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have two dates where one field is a datetime field and the other is a nullable datetime field. I want to subtract date2 from date 1 and if date2 is null subtract it from today.

My code :

Model :

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date1 {get;set;}        
    public DateTime? Date2 {get;set;}
    public int Diff {get;set;}      
}
```

Controller Action :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel();
    model.Date1=today;
    model.Date2 = today.AddDays(5);
    model.Diff = (model.Date1 - (model.Date2 != null ? model.Date2 : today)).Days;//Error
    return View(model);
}
```

I am getting a compilation error

> Error CS1061  'TimeSpan?' does not contain a definition for 'Days' and no accessible extension method 'Days' accepting a first argument of type 'TimeSpan?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If one of the datetimes is null, what should the result be?

Comment: Why does it need to be nullable?

You can just check DateTime = DateTime.MinValue

Comment: Try `model.Date2 ?? today` instead.  The issue is that you still use a `DateTime?` in the calculation when `Date2` is not null which results in a `TimeSpan?`.

Comment: Try to change `(model.Date2 != null ? model.Date2 : today)` to `(model.Date2.HasValue ? model.Date2.Value : today)`.

Comment: you can just add optional navigation `(task.DueDate - DateTime.Now)?.Days` 
it should work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TimeSpan?` means `Nullable<TimeSpan>` which is a different structure from `TimeSpan` and it doesn't have a `Days` property.

Instead of that, you can use it's [`Value` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.value?view=netframework-4.8) and you can call it's `Days` after it like;

```
model.Diff = (model.Date1 - (model.Date2 != null ? model.Date2 : today)).Value.Days;
```

Or as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344339/to-get-the-date-difference-between-a-datetime-and-nullable-datetime#comment99293827_56344391) by juharr, you can use `model.Date2 ?? today` which returns `model.Date2` *if* it's not `null` or returns `today` if `model.Date2` is `null` like;

```
model.Diff = (model.Date1 - (model.Date2 ?? today)).Days;
```

Comment: Even better to use `model.Date2 ?? today` and avoid the `TimeSpan?` altogether.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, mentioned that as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date1 {get;set;}        
    public DateTime? Date2 {get;set;}
    public int Diff {get;set;}      
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    SampleViewModel model = new SampleViewModel();
    model.Date1=today;
    model.Date2 = today.AddDays(5);
    model.Diff = (int)(model.Date1 - (model.Date2 ?? today)).TotalDays;
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the null coalescing operator (`??`) to make sure you are using a non-nullable value in the calculation like this.

```
model.Diff = (model.Date1 - (model.Date2 ?? today)).Days;
```

This ensures that the calculation is done on two `DateTime`s instead of a `DateTime` and a `DateTime?`.  When one value in a calculation is nullable the result is going to be nullable.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to move your logic inside your model and use the null coalescing operator :

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public SampleViewModel(DateTime date1, DateTime? date2 = null){
        Date1 = date1;
        Date2 = date2;
    }

    public DateTime Date1 { get; set; }        
    public DateTime? Date2 { get; set; }
    public int Diff => (Date1 - (Date2 ?? DateTime.Now)).Days;     
}
```

Usage:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var today = DateTime.Now;
    var model = new SampleViewModel(today, today.AddDays(5));

    return View(model);
}
```